# Uncompressing *.Z files in a folder returns error

Tags: ubuntu, gzip

To estract a single .Z file from a given folder I use `uncompress file.Z` in a terminal and it works flawlessy. If, in the same folder, I want to extract all the .Z files I use `uncompress "*.Z"` or `uncompress '*.Z'` or `uncompress \*.Z`. But they all give the same error:

`gzip: *.Z: No such file or directory`

(There I have used various forms of quotes just to show that quotes should not be the problem).

Same story if I use the "extended" extension proper of each file, that is `file.fitz.Z`. How do I uncompress all the .Z files? What is going wrong?

PS: This has already been posted on the SO, but no luck yet (although I could not imagine the question is that hard to answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like everything you have tried is escaping the special character `*` causing it to be interpreted literally instead of as a wildcard.

Try using this instead:

```
uncompress *.Z
```

---

`"*.Z"`
Double quotes will preserve the literal value of the `*`

> Enclosing characters in double quotes (‘"’) preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘\’, and, when history expansion is enabled, ‘!’.

`'*.Z'` Single quotes will preserve the literal value of everything

> Enclosing characters in single quotes (‘'’) preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.

`\*.Z` An escape (backslash) will also preserve the literal value of `*`

> A non-quoted backslash ‘\’ is the Bash escape character. It preserves the literal value of the next character that follows, with the exception of newline.

Comment: I will go and hide my head under the sand: it worked! Thanks\

Comment: @Py-ser, the only reason I remember is because I have made the same mistake in the past. :)